# Problem with BranchPythonOperator to TaskGroup

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I got the following DAG

```
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


def select_next_branch():
    if some_condition:
        next_task_ = 'tasks.inner'
    else:
        next_task_ = 'end'
    logging.info(f'next_task: {next_task_}')
    return next_task_


with DAG(dag_id='poc_branch_tasks',
         description='Branching with task group POC',
         schedule_interval=None,
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         tags=['poc', 'branch', 'task_group']) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    branch = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='branch',
                                  python_callable=select_next_branch)

    with TaskGroup(group_id='tasks') as task_group:
        inner_one = DummyOperator(task_id='inner')

    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start >> branch
    branch >> end
    branch >> task_group >> end
```

[image]

When `some_condition` is satisfied the flow go correctly from `branch` to `task_group.inner`, otherwise it should be from `branch` to `end`, but instead of execute `end`  this is skipped. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `trigger_rule='one_success'` for `end` task. The default `trigger_rule` is all_success.

> all_success (default): All upstream tasks have succeeded

However, your `end` task is dependent for both Branch operator and `inner` task. When `inner` task is skipped, `end` cannot triggered because one of the upstream task is not "success".

The trigger rule one_success will try to execute this `end` task if either of Branch operator or `inner` task is succeeded.

```py
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', trigger_rule='one_success')
```

Comment: It works! That's what was I missed! Thank you!